# Undefined query function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

so I'm currently using the following code to execute queries;

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var config = require('./config');
var pool = mysql.createPool(config.mysql);

function query(statement){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
      if(err) reject(err);

      connection.query(statement, function(err, row){
        connection.release();

        if(err){
          reject(err);
        }

        resolve(row);        
      })
    });
  });
}

module.exports = {
  pool: pool,
  query: query
};
```

Whenever the query function is called it results in a undefined error;

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined`

I'm quite out of ideas why this could be, this would be `connection.getConnection` is not returning a proper connection, would this mean my credentials are wrong in my `createPool` function?

**config.mysql**

```
mysql: {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'site',
    connectionLimit : 10,           
    multipleStatements : true  
  }
```

Comment: You aren't defining `query` anywhere.

Comment: @CharlieFish sorry? `function query()`

Edit: I see now - this is precisely how errors can be the smallest things, thanks!

Comment: Of course! Hopefully my answer gives more context. Feel free to accept or upvote my answer if it helped. And let me know if you need me to add anymore context or information to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on the following line you are passing in the `query` function when you should be passing in a string.

```
connection.query(query, function(err, row){
```

`query` in that case should be a string. But you defined `query` as a function (`function query(){`)

If you change the line to something LIKE the following this should work.

```
connection.query("SELECT * from Users", function(err, row){
```

Comment: Somehow I'm still getting the same error;

see updated post for updated function

Comment: @Borda What happens when you add `console.log(statement)`. What does that print? Right above `connection.query(statement`

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/312b7f0741d2b35af8a9c80618c76a72.png

Somehow connection is undefined.

Edit: when I log `connection` it returns `undefined`

Comment: @Borda You are correct. What happens if you rename the pool variable to pool instead of `connection`?

Comment: Err, I changed it to the above function (see updated post), now I'm getting a odd `TypeError: Cannot read property 'acquireTimeout' of undefined` error.

Comment: @Borda You removed the object being passed into `mysql.createPool`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm stupid, however; it's giving me the same error on line 11.

Comment: @Borda I have no idea what line 11 is.

Comment: `connection`.query(statement, function(err, row){

Comment: @Borda I don't believe that error is legit. You aren't using `acquireTimeout` anywhere in your code. So it sounds like an internal MySQL error. Can you please edit your question with the **entire** error output.

Comment: I've just done, for some reason I wasn't getting the proper error when I logged it outside the promise, I now logged it and it indeed gave me 'Access denied for user \'root\'@\'localhost\' (using password: NO)'. 

Damn human errors..

Comment: @Borda Great! So you are set then? `Access denied for user \'root\'@\'localhost\' (using password: NO)` is an error that is completely unrelated to your question and unrelated to your code at this point. Sounds like you need to update your `config.mysql` to ensure you are passing in the correct username, password, host, database, and port.

Comment: Yep, wrong password.

*Facepalms to eternity* Thanks for helping me out though!

Comment: @Borda No problem!! Glad it helped. Feel free to accept and upvote the answer if it helped you. Good luck in your future coding!!!